# Write the attributes of an object into a txt file

Tags: python

So i am trying to write to a text file with all the attributes of an object called item.

I was able to access the information with:

```
>>>print(*vars(item).values()])
125001 John Smith 12 First Road London N1 55 74
```

but when i try write it into the text file:

```
with open('new_student_data.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(*vars(item).values())
```

it throws an error as writelines() only takes one argument.

how can i write all the attributes of item to a single line in the text file?

Comment: `str()` will do?

Comment: You need to pass a single *list* of *strings*, not an arbitrary number of arguments.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to use `pickle`?

Comment: If you're using Python 3 then you can also supply a file pointer to `print` as the `file=` argument

Comment: @PatrickHaugh that worked perfectly. If you write that as an answer, i can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open('new_student_data.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i in vars(item).values():
        f.write(f"{i}\n")
```

If `file.writelines` only takes an iterable and doesn't support `*args`, you can always iterate over your `list` and write it with `file.write`.

Answer (score 1):

You can just print as follows:

```
with open('new_student_data.txt', 'w') as f:
  print(*vars(item).values(), file=f)
```

Answer (score 1):

Every class is capable of outputting a dictionary by calling `__dict__` method. This way you are getting the attribute name and the value as a dictionary, then you could simply iterate through it and write it to a txt file:

```
with open('params.txt'), 'w') as f:
    for param, value in params.__dict__.items():
        if not param.startswith("__"):
            f.write(f"{param}:{value}\n")
```

Here I am also getting rid of default class attributes that start with "__". Hope this helps